# Ember.js: How to get meta data of multiple requests to same url

Tags: ember.js

I am populating my page with data of multiple models like so:

*index route:*

```
model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        books: this.store.find('book', {order: 'new'}),
        featuredList: this.store.find('list', {type: 'featured'}),
        recommendedList: this.store.find('list', {type: 'recomended'}),
    });
}
```

As you can see, two of the requests are made to same data source: `list`

And I need to get the meta data of the last two requests.
Currently, I can only get meta data only on the last request like below:

*index controller:*

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    listMeta: function() {
        return Ember.copy(this.store.metadataFor('list'));
   }.property()
});
```

How can I get the meta data of both requests to `list`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you have control over the api consider separating the routes or adding in additional metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get the names of the each lists and I was trying to use meta data for that. Since ember data accepts `json` in certain format I could not just add list names as an attribute to the `json`.

So I sent the names in as meta data and tried to receive them in the `controller` but it turns out that I can acces meta data of each request in `setupController`. So I just did the following.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);

    controller.set('books', model.books);
    controller.set('featuredList', model.featuredList);
    controller.set('featuredListName', model.featuredList.meta.listName);
    controller.set('recommendedList', model.recommendedList);
    controller.set('recommendedListName', model.recommendedList.meta.listName);

}
```